# JQuery Dialog not displaying imput type text

Tags: jquery, dialog, html-input

I have been trying to add a standard html :`<imput type="text" value="">` into a JQuery dialog box, but it does not show up. I have tried with a selector and it was working.

I don't understand why it doesn't with text imputs.

Comment: change imput to input. hopefully this was just a typo in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo? **Input** vs. Imput?

`<input type="text" value="">`

Answer (score 1):

Double check that tag - you wrote imput twice in your question so it might be imput in your code. Try this:

```
<input type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It was done here: 
[modal-form](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

Also, it could be that you are spelling input "imput" (with an 'm' as opposed to an 'n').